# Swagger composition / inheritance

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to document a REST API using Swagger.  A simplified JSON response from our API looks like:

```
{ 
    "data": {
        "type": "person"
        "id": "1"
        "attributes": {
          "name": "Joe"
          "age": 32
          ...
        }
        "links": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{ 
    "data": {
        "type": "job"
        "id": "22"
        "attributes": {
          "name": "Manager"
          "location": "Somewhere"
          ...
        }
        "links": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Their Swagger definitions for a successful GET might look like:

```
   '200':
      description: OK.
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          data:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
              type:
                type: string
              attributes:
                $ref: '#/definitions/person'
```

or

```
   '200':
      description: OK.
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          data:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
              type:
                type: string
              attributes:
                $ref: '#/definitions/job'
```

There's potentially a lot of repetition like this in our Swagger file.  Is it possible to define these responses to share the common parts?  i.e. I don't want to type out or copy/paste this part tens of times:

```
   '200':
      description: OK.
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          data:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
              type:
                type: string
```

I couldn't see how this would work using the *discriminator* field, or using $ref.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `allOf` to do composition (in conjunction with `discriminator` you can do inheritance but it's not really functionnal)

`allOf` is used with an array of schema or reference, it will create a new definition containing all properties of all definitions in the array.

Given that you want some of your definitions to share `id` and `type` properties, it is done this way:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: API

paths: {}

definitions:
  SharedDefinition:
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      type:
        type: string

  Person:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/SharedDefinition'
      - properties:
          firstname:
            type: string
          lastname:
            type: string

  JobSubDefinition:
    properties:
      name:
        type: string

  Job:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/SharedDefinition'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/JobSubDefinition'
```

In this example:

- Person = SharedDefinition + inline definition
- Job = SharedDefinition + JobSubDefinition

More about this in

- [Writing OpenAPI (Swagger) Specification Tutorial – Part 4 – Advanced Data Modeling](http://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-4-advanced-data-modeling/) (disclosure: I wrote this tutorial)
- [OpenAPI Specification#models-with-composition](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#models-with-composition)

Comment: I'm not sure if this definition will work for me. My get function needs to return a type that, in your definition, could be either a Person or a JobSubDefinition. (This makes no sense in your example but it does in mine.) So I created a base object, which is SharedDefinition in your example. I want to declare that my get function returns a SharedDefinition, so it could be either one. Does this example get me there?